# Merging Pandas duplicate columns with the same name to a new row within dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to combine columns with the same name and make a new row within the dataframe. Here's an example

Lets say I have a dataframe with the following columns: `[UniqueId, Company Name, Job Title, Company Name.1, and Job Title.1]`. The values within the columns with `'.1'` need to be added as a new row under the original column names (`Company Name` and `Job Title`).

My thought process was to separate the dataframe into two separate dataframes, rename Company Name.1 and Job Title.1 to remove the '.1' and merge the two dataframes. This would be quite tedious I have around 70 columns. Is there a built-in solution for this within pandas?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there small input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If the column name pattern is consistent you can automate the split, rename the columns to match and concatenate the frames -

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'UniqueId': [1,2,3],
    'Company Name' : ['Company A','Company B','Company C'],
    'Job Title' : ['Software Dev A','Software Dev B','Software Dev C'],
    'Another Column' : ['abc','def','ghi'],
    'Company Name.1' : ['Company D','Company E','Company F'],
    'Job Title.1' : ['Software Dev D','Software Dev E','Software Dev F'],
    'Another Column.1' : ['jkl','mno','pqr'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

id_col = ['UniqueId']

cols = [col for col in df.columns if (not col in id_col and not col.endswith('.1'))]
cols_1 = [col for col in df.columns if (not col in id_col and col.endswith('.1'))]

df1 = df[id_col + cols]
df2 = df[id_col + cols_1].copy()
df2[id_col] = df2[id_col] + len(df1) #update unique ID to continue from where 1 left off
df2.columns = df1.columns

new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
print(new_df)
```

|  | UniqueId | Company | Name | Job Title | Another Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Company | A | Software Dev A | abc |
| 1 | 2 | Company | B | Software Dev B | def |
| 2 | 3 | Company | C | Software Dev C | ghi |
| 0 | 4 | Company | D | Software Dev D | jkl |
| 1 | 5 | Company | E | Software Dev E | mno |
| 2 | 6 | Company | F | Software Dev F | pqr |